# polymorphist's jest and emrakul

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Polymorphist's Jest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polymorphist%27s%20Jest) says each creature target player controls loses all abilities and becomes a blue Frog with a base power and toughness 1/1. My question is...  how would this work with Emrakul? Like let's say a player attacks with Emrakul, you cast Polymoprhist's Jest and then lightning bolt Emrakul.

My assumption is that the defending player would still have to sacrifice six permanents because the attack is earlier in the stack.

And when Emrakul hits the graveyard does it go into the graveyard and stay there or does the graveyard still get shuffled into the library?

Comment: Can you please make an attempt to generalize your titles in the future? You have a history of asking questions with nothing but card names. This makes it difficult to identify duplicates. Regarding the first question, *"If a creature loses all abilities after being declared as an attacker, do abilities that would trigger on attack still trigger?"* Someone could ask the exact same question using Turn/Burn and Ulamog. A better question title is simply a shortened version of the actual question, like *"Do attack triggers still trigger if the source loses all abilities?"*

Comment: I also want to point out that you also asked two questions in one, making it hard for me to revise your current title in a way that would still describe both of your questions. Please ask two questions in the future when you have two questions. That way, if one of them is a duplicate, we can easily identify it, and if it has a poor title, we can easily improve upon it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defending player will still have to sacrifice 6 permenants, and Emrakul and the rest of the graveyard will still be shuffled into the controller's graveyard.

Anailator still happens, not exactly because the attack is earlier in the stack like you say ("the attack" doesn't go on the stack). But as soon as Emrakul is declared as an attacker, the "when attacks" ability triggers and goes in the stack. After that, it doesn't matter what happens to Emrakul. Best to kill it in the beginning of combat step.

It still gets shuffled back in because that trigger happens "when it is put into the graveyard". And by that time, it's back to normal, sitting in the graveyard with its abilities. Note that if it said "when Emrakul dies..." instead, then it would NOT be shuffled back in, because when it dies triggers care about the state of the object as it was on battlefield, and the ability didn't exist in the battlefield.

Comment: @neubert, It's "back to normal" because moving a card from one zone to another causes the cessation of the object in the original zone and the creation of a new object in the new zone. The new object is created from what's on the card. CR 400.7

Comment: @ikegami is there a reference for when a card reverts? I'm having trouble reconciling that the graveyard should be shuffled, it seems to me that the shuffle trigger would happen from the battlefield, but he doesn't have the ability there. Would it work the same way if it was a "dies" trigger?

Comment: @JakeP; every time the gamestate changes, everything is checked again; starting with the text on the cards and applying each layer of effects.

Comment: @JakeP, my answer says that "Dies" triggers are NOT the same. That DOES trigger based on the the state of the object as it was on the battlefield. But "Enters the graveyard" triggers do not care where they came from, or what it was when it was there.

Comment: @Jake P, Loosely speaking, the reversion occurs on zone change. You can't find the rule because there's technically no reversion. The object on the 'field is different than the obj in the graveyard (400.7). The one on the 'field has no abilities because they were removed by PJ. The only in the graveyard has its abilities since nothing removed them. // Emrakul's ability triggers from the graveyard (based on the game state after the event) rather than from the 'field (based on the game state before the event) since it's not a leaves-the-battlefield trigger like "when this dies" (603.6d, 603.6c).

Comment: I admit to still being confused by this. Where does it say Emrakul's ability triggers from the graveyard? the key text seems to be here, from 603.6 "Trigger events that involve objects changing zones are called "zone-change triggers." Many abilities with zone-change triggers attempt to do something to that object after it changes zones. **During resolution**, these abilities look for the object in the zone that it moved to." (Emphasis mine). The implication here (to me) is that the trigger would go on the stack before Emrakul actually changes zones. 400.7d also supports this implication.

Comment: I think I might be reading too much into it, but i can't see why a "dies" trigger wouldn't go off, but a "put into a graveyard from anywhere" would.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I have resolved my confusion. I didn't actually think I was correct, but rather was trying to make sense of the rules. I guess that the text in 600.3c "Leaves-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent moves from the battlefield to another zone" indicates that it should trigger from the battlefield? It wasn't clear to me that it should trigger from there and not the 'yard, but I suppose that must be the correct reading of that rule?

Comment: @JakeP "603.6d Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions." Leave-the-battlefield abilities are listed to an exception to this, but enters-the-graveyard abilities are not, so they are covered by that rule.

Comment: @JakeP When the frog dies, moving from the battlefield to the graveyard is a state-based action. Triggers cannot be placed on the stack in the middle of a state-based action, because no player receives priority to do so. After the state-based action is completed, Emrakul is *completely* in the graveyard, no longer affected by Polymorphist's Jest, and so it triggers. THEN a player gets priority, and the trigger is added to the stack. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score -3):

To "die" and "put into the graveyard" are the same thing (See rule 700.6).
In this case I think Emrakul's ability does not trigger.

700.6. The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.” It is used only when referring
to creatures.

Comment: This is wrong. You own rules quote contradicts what you said. Die does not mean "put into graveyard". It means "put into graveyard from the battlefield."

Comment: Further, Emrakul's ability is "put into a graveyard _from anywhere_", and will still trigger despite not having the ability on the battlefield.